# Memory leak caused by ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler being referenced by ThreadLocal$Values

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak where my activity is leaked as long as the animations on the UI is played. If I start the activity (and play the animations and exit by pressing "back" key) 10 times, I would have 10 activity references on the heap.

By dumping the heap, I found a reference chain like this:

````
```
java.lang.Thread (main Thread)
    -> localValues java.lang.ThreadLocal$Values
        -> table java.lang.Object[128]
            -> [99] android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler
                -> mDelayedAnims java.util.ArrayList
                    -> array java.lang.Object[40]
                        -> [7] android.animation.ValueAnimator
                            -> animator listeners
                                -> views referenced by listeners
                                    -> view context (my activity)
```
````

All my animations do not have a long duration, they finish within 2 seconds and they don't have a long start offset. One thing I should mention is that some of my animations are chained - one is started from onAnimationEnd() of another animation. But the total length is still relatively short compared to the duration of user interactions.

Do you have any clue why my activity is leaked?

Comment: Are these animation canceled when the activity is destroyed?

Comment: No. But these animation ends themselves within several seconds.

Comment: However if you do not cancel them, they will hold the view that hold the context (Activity) so memory leaks.

Comment: By reading the API 25 source code, I found that ViewPropertyAnimator gets hold of its view (in field mView) at construction time and never release it, even if you call cancel(). So the problem is still that why the animator itself is held by some ThreadLocal variable.

Comment: The animation is implemented by `Handler` and `Runnable` (postDelayed etc), if the activity is destroyed while the animation has not been finished yet , it will hold the view refrence.

Comment: Yes. But these animations finish within several seconds. The time takes to start the activity 10 times and dump the memory (which reveals the leak) is tens of times longer than the animation duration.

Comment: @ZiliFENG It doesn't release it because ViewPropertyAnimator is constructed in View.java. So when the view is destroyed, so is the ViewPropertyAnimator. The only issue arises so View isn't being leaked by ViewPropertyAnimator. When Runnables reference other objects, those Runnables need to be deferenced by calling `cancel()`.